# Shadows not drawing on UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm refactoring a Swift 3 project to Swift 4 and I've encountered a situation where buttons that previously had a shadows applied to them no longer draw a shadow.

I'm using this code to draw the shadow:

```
extension UIButton {  
  func drawShadow() {
    self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    self.layer.shadowRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5    
  }
}
```

I call the code to draw the shadow in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` using this code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    buttonArray = [self.buttonOne, self.buttonTwo, self.buttonThree, self.buttonFour]
    buttonArray.forEach { button in
      button.subviews.filter{$0 is UIImageView}.forEach({ imageView in
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      })
      button.clipsToBounds = false
      button.drawShadow()
    }
}
```

I've tried addding the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in other spots to see if I can get it to draw. I've tried `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear`, etc. I've tried nuking the storyboard and "starting over", by laying out the buttons again, cleaning derived data, nuking the simulator from both terminal and within Xcode.

The buttons are contained within a `UIStackView`. I've got two horizontal stackviews containing two buttons embedded within a vertical stackview. If anyone's got any suggestions re: what else to try, I welcome your suggestions. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code, I have changed the shadowOffset

```
func drawShadow() {
    self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5    
  }
```

Comment: That's it! I also changed the `cornerRadius`. Thank you!